# how to install uuid package on centos without root

Tags: linux, installation, centos, uuid

I want to build something on one centos 7 machine, and it tells me "No package 'uuid' found". So I want to know how to install uuid just for me, not other people. And I do not have root privileges.

Thanks!

[No package 'uuid' found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6Lts.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please note that your question seem more suitable for SuperUser than here.

Comment: Hi, you should take the [tour] and read [ask].  @ewong is right on.

Comment: OhOh, I'm sorry, thanks for remind me.

Answer (score 0):

You need **root** access.

First install snap and then use the following command to install uuid:

```sh
sudo snap install uuid-tool
```